# Difference between lightning and ui tags

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, ui

I've begun to work on lightning component last days ago and I wonder why two different tags exist for the same things. For example, what is the different between `lightning:select` and `ui:inputSelect`? All of them are used in lightning apps and more `lightning:select` already have "lightning style", so why should I use `ui:inputSelect` instead of `lightning:select`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find the answer in the Winter 17 release notes [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_base_lightning_components.htm)

> You can find base Lightning components in the lightning namespace to complement the existing ui namespace components. In instances where there are matching ui and lightning namespace components, we recommend that you use the lightning namespace component. The lightning namespace components are optimized for common use cases. Beyond being equipped with the Lightning Design System styling, they handle accessibility, real-time interaction, and enhanced error messages.

Comment: same doc is now updated at : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_overview.htm
with all component list and more detailed data regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The `ui` namespace components are being retired and won't be supported beyond Summer 21.

See the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm). They include a list of suggested replacements within the `lightning` namespace.

> The ui components are scheduled for retirement in all Salesforce orgs in Summer ’21. Use similar components in the lightning namespace instead. Retiring our legacy components enables us to focus on components that match the latest web standards in performance, accessibility, user experience, and internationalization.